# Unpublish sitecore item programmatically

Tags: c#, sitecore, publish, sitecore8

I know it's possible to publish item from code level with `Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager`. I don't see there option to unpublish an item.

Is it possible in some way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set value of `__Never publish` field to `1` (which is how Sitecore stores `true` boolean value) and **publish** the item.

Yes, it's publishing, but because value of `__Never publish` is set to true, Sitecore will remove the item from the `web` database.

You can also set value of this field by using `item.Publishing.NeverPublish` property.

Something like this should do the trick:

```cs
item.Editing.BeginEdit();
item.Publishing.NeverPublish = true;
item.Editing.EndEdit();

PublishManager.PublishItem(item, targets, item.Languages, false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Not in a workflow

Items marked as `NeverPublish` will be unpublished during publishing. Since `NeverPublish` is a shared field all versions will be unpublished.

```
bool originalNeverPublish = item.Publishing.NeverPublish;

item.Editing.BeginEdit();
item.Publishing.NeverPublish = true;
item.Editing.EndEdit();

PublishManager.PublishItem(item, targets, item.Languages, false, false);

item.Editing.BeginEdit();
item.Publishing.NeverPublish = originalNeverPublish;
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

### In a workflow

If the item is in a workflow, publishing will publish all versions of the item that is in a `Final`/`IsApproved` state, ignoring the value of `NeverPublish`. We should instead change the workflow state of the versions we want to unpublish.

In the example below I assume that the initial state isn't marked as `Final`/`IsApproved`.

```
var workflowProvider = item.Database.WorkflowProvider;
var workflow = workflowProvider.GetWorkflow(item);

foreach (var version in item.Versions.GetVersions())
{
    if (workflow.IsApproved(version))
    {
        workflow.Start(version);
    }
}

PublishManager.PublishItem(item, targets, item.Languages, false, false);
```

Answer (score -4):

Publishing an item simply moves it to `Web` database.

Just remove your item from that database to unpublish it.

Comment: This isn't helpful and should be considered bad practice. Many Sitecore solutions have multiple web databases, especially in distributed environments. Further to this the web databases should not be modified directly. @Marek Musielak has explained the correct way of doing this.